# What is the TableController class for and where are its methods used?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I've been starting out with Azure and have chosen to set up a Mobile Service using .NET in VS. I've been learning about the constituents of the Azure Todo get-started server project.

One thing I'm struggling to understand (even with extensive Googling) is what the TableController methods are for? I understand that TableController exposes the table to HTTP requests? But when I access data from my client I'm using ".LookupAsync" or ".UpdateAsync" methods on the Table returned by my MobileServiceClient instance.

Are the GetAllToDoItems(..), PathToDoItem(..), GetToDoItem(..), PostToDoItem(..), DeleteToDoItem(..) methods in the TableController being used behind the scenes somewhere when I make those calls on the MobileServiceClient Table?

Can I access those methods from my client? Are these methods standard/required method names?

Is TableController a good place to put server code for authorisation? E.g. the classic example of only returning that user's records?

Thanks for any help,
Tom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I access those methods from my client? Are these methods standard/required method names?

At currently, Azure mobile app support C# and node.js as its backend language. From the [Get started article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-value-prop), we can know that we can take advantage of Mobile App using native SDKs whether you're building native iOS, Android, and Windows apps or cross-platform Xamarin or Cordova (Phonegap) apps. We can see a lot of functions like GetAllToDoItems(..), PathToDoItem(..), GetToDoItem(..), PostToDoItem(..), DeleteToDoItem(..) in the backend project. This method is a MVC controller action name. Please note the SDK functions are the important, as we can see below, the backend project has a function called GetTodoItem.

```html
     public SingleResult<TodoItem> GetTodoItem(string id)
        {
            return Lookup(id);
        }
```

However the function Lookup which under the namespace "Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server" is the key method in this function:

[image]

> Is TableController a good place to put server code for authorisation? E.g. the classic example of only returning that user's records?

If you want to add authentication, I think [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-auth) may be give you helps. Just use Azure AD for example, if you want to protect some table controller, we only need to configure Azure AD then add [Authorize] attribute before table controller, it is not necessary to add authrize code in that table controller.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. So the TableController methods are exposing these Server API methods to the clients? Why does calling `MobileService.GetTable<TodoItem>().ToListAsync();` result in `TableControllerInstance.GetAllTodoItems()` being called at the server side? I think I'm missing a step. And why doesn't it matter if I rename the `GetAllTodoItems()` to anything `GetXXXXX()`, but it breaks if the method name doesn't start with `Get`?

Comment: Yes, it helps us to expose data to devices. But if we use TableController, we need to add ZUMO-API-VERSION as its header when we use http request. Of course if we choose Azure mobile app SDK in client. we only need to call the function that the SDK have. For your second issue, it is a .NET MVC issue. If we define GET in action name, it will default define as Http Get function.

Comment: Execllent quick review.  For more information, you may want to read chapters 1-3 of the ZUMO book - http://aka.ms/zumobook