# Issues with azure mobile app service from wpf application

Tags: .net, azure, mobile, azure-mobile-services, azure-web-app-service

I am new to mobile app services and azure, I want to get the app service layer working then port it over to an Xamarin app, so I figured I would just try a simple wpf application to consume the service.

I downloaded the sample ToDo service in .NET/c# provided by azure and have it published, however I am getting these exceptions and am stumped.

Here is the client code, which throws a Bad Request exception, I've tried multiple calls to the app service such as inserting, updating, etc but they all fail.

```
string url = @"https://mydomain.azurewebsites.net";
MobileServiceClient client = new MobileServiceClient(url);
return await client.GetTable<TodoItem>().ToListAsync();

public class TodoItem
{
    string id;
    string name;
    bool done;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "text")]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "complete")]
    public bool Done
    {
        get { return done; }
        set { done = value; }
    }

}
```

App Service
TodoItem

```
public class TodoItem : EntityData
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }

        public bool Complete { get; set; }
    }
```

Code TodoController

```
    // GET tables/TodoItem
    public IQueryable<TodoItem> GetAllTodoItems()
    {
        return Query();
    }

    // GET tables/TodoItem/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
    public SingleResult<TodoItem> GetTodoItem(string id)
    {
        return Lookup(id);
    }

    // PATCH tables/TodoItem/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
    public Task<TodoItem> PatchTodoItem(string id, Delta<TodoItem> patch)
    {
        return UpdateAsync(id, patch);
    }

    // POST tables/TodoItem
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostTodoItem(TodoItem item)
    {
        TodoItem current = await InsertAsync(item);
        return CreatedAtRoute("Tables", new { id = current.Id }, current);
    }

    // DELETE tables/TodoItem/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
    public Task DeleteTodoItem(string id)
    {
        return DeleteAsync(id);
    }
```

App service Logging and exceptions

```
Method: GET, RequestUri: 'https://mydomain.azurewebsites.net/tables/TodoItem', Version: 1.1, Content: <null>, Headers:
{
  X-ZUMO-FEATURES: TT
  X-ZUMO-INSTALLATION-ID: cd7127a1-efc4-4967-b646-e99a069976cb
  Accept: application/json
  User-Agent: ZUMO/1.3
  User-Agent: (lang=Managed; os=Windows; os_version=6.1.65536.7601; arch=Win32NT; version=1.3.30324.0)
  X-ZUMO-VERSION: ZUMO/1.3 (lang=Managed; os=Windows; os_version=6.1.65536.7601; arch=Win32NT; version=1.3.30324.0)
}}

{StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Date: Thu, 02 Mar 2017 02:44:30 GMT
  Set-Cookie: ARRAffinity=1b2631dc149e564d651190bdb0b6895025c984e8ad5bea83fb1e545ec292facb;Path=/;Domain=mydomain.azurewebsites.net
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Length: 220
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
}}

Application: 2017-03-02T03:48:26  PID[6016] Information Request, Method=GET, Url=https://mydomain.azurewebsites.net/tables/TodoItem, Message='https://mydomain.azurewebsites.net/tables/TodoItem'
Application: 2017-03-02T03:48:26  PID[6016] Information Message='TodoItem', Operation=DefaultHttpControllerSelector.SelectController
Application: 2017-03-02T03:48:26  PID[6016] Information Message='mydomainService.Controllers.TodoItemController', Operation=DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create
Application: 2017-03-02T03:48:26  PID[6016] Information Message='mydomainService.Controllers.TodoItemController', Operation=HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController
Application: 2017-03-02T03:48:53  PID[6016] Information Message='Selected action 'GetAllTodoItems()'', Operation=ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction
Application: 2017-03-02T03:48:53  PID[6016] Information Operation=HttpActionBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync
Application: 2017-03-02T03:48:53  PID[6016] Information Operation=TableQueryFilter.OnActionExecutingAsync
Application: 2017-03-02T03:48:53  PID[6016] Information Operation=EnableQueryAttribute.OnActionExecutingAsync
Application: 2017-03-02T03:48:53  PID[6016] Information Message='Will use same 'JsonMediaTypeFormatter' formatter', Operation=JsonMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
Application: 2017-03-02T03:48:53  PID[6016] Information Message='Selected formatter='JsonMediaTypeFormatter', content-type='application/json; charset=utf-8'', Operation=DefaultContentNegotiator.Negotiate
Application: 2017-03-02T03:48:53  PID[6016] Information Operation=TableControllerConfigAttribute.OnActionExecutingAsync, Status=400 (BadRequest)
Application: 2017-03-02T03:48:53  PID[6016] Information Operation=EnableQueryAttribute.OnActionExecutedAsync, Status=400 (BadRequest)
Application: 2017-03-02T03:48:53  PID[6016] Information Operation=TableQueryFilter.OnActionExecutedAsync, Status=400 (BadRequest)
Application: 2017-03-02T03:48:54  PID[6016] Information Operation=TodoItemController.ExecuteAsync, Status=400 (BadRequest)
Application: 2017-03-02T03:48:54  PID[6016] Information Response, Status=400 (BadRequest), Method=GET, Url=https://mydomain.azurewebsites.net/tables/TodoItem?$select=Text,Complete,Id,Version,CreatedAt,UpdatedAt,Deleted, Message='Content-type='application/json; charset=utf-8', content-length=unknown'
Application: 2017-03-02T03:48:54  PID[6016] Information Operation=JsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync
Application: 2017-03-02T03:48:55  PID[6016] Information Operation=TodoItemController.Dispose
```

Comment: How did you consume the service in a WPF app? I'm really having trouble making Mobile Apps work in a WPF app. How did you create the project, did you have to create a .net standard class library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd rewind and go through the tutorials again.  You've done something wrong and have not provided enough information to say what exactly.  Explicitly, you have not included the code that is actually doing the queries.

Comment: I am pretty sure the TodoController.cs code is correct and that is where the queries are done. Here is a quick discussion about it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41091994/what-is-the-tablecontroller-class-for-and-where-are-its-methods-used

Comment: The queries are partially done on the server and partially on the client.  I work on the team and am intimate with both the client and server codebase.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I am still a bit confused about how to return all the todo items from the db. Hopefully you can help clear it up. From the azure portal I did the mobile quick start and downloaded the .net backend for theTodoItem tutorial. Above is the TodoController, are you saying I need to additional code there? I thought client.GetTable<TodoItem>.().ToListAsync(); would call public IQueryable<TodoItem> GetAllTodoItems() because its method name starts with GetAll?

If that is not correct, can you help me understand the basic code needed to just return all the todo items from the db?

Comment: Read the book on this subject - http://aka.ms/zumobook - this is covered in CHapter 3.

Comment: Thanks, I will follow their example. My underlying frustration is that microsoft's tutorial for this does not require the user to add extra code to the todo service tutorial like they do in chapter 3. It seems there is an issue with microsoft's documentation or it is correct but there is an issue else where. Here is the link to microsofts walkthrough of this example, except instead of using a wpf client it uses an xamarin client. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started

Comment: I wrote that documentation, so it's on me.  :-) . I'm working on improvements to the tutorial flow, so I'll take this into consideration.

Comment: And just an additional note - we don't actually test WPF anywhere.  It's theoretically possible, but I'd need to write a test case to see what problems occur in the WPF case.